# I can not deploy my project under tomcat 6

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat6

I can not deploy my project under tomcat 6.
Before, knowing that everything works perfectly, 
after a certain time (I do not know what I did), but
every time I filed my project in the webapps directory then I run tomcat 6.

it does not start then deletes the contents of the directory of my project...
I find the following empty directories: Projetct_Name/WEB-INF

when I run tomcat directly by clicking the startup.bat file it works.
but when I run from netbeans, it does not work

below my log

```
INFO: Initialisation de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-8080
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 250 ms
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration host-manager.xml
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration manager.xml
31 juil. 2015 10:20:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration servlet.xml
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Déploiement du répertoire saiku de l'application web
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-8080
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1579 ms
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: The web application [/servlet] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/servlet]
31 juil. 2015 10:20:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Le conteneur org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/servlet] n'a pas été démarré
```

someone has an idea?
thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide the logs of tomcat.

Comment: I added the logs of tomcat